# Tomcat embded server classnotfound exception

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat9

I am trying to create a emebded tomcat server for my jsp servlet application.
When I added the below dependency to the application, I am getting FileNotFoundException
exceptions while running the main application.     How to fix this issue? Below is the dependency that I have added to pom.xml

C:\Users\testuser.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.2.11\jaxb-api.jar

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\testuser\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.2.11\jaxb-api.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:221)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:383)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:318)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:270)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)   
    

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>



package launch;

import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot;

import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

        //The port that we should run on can be set into an environment variable
        //Look for that variable and default to 8080 if it isn't there.
        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8080";
        }

        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));


        StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
        

        // Declare an alternative location for your "WEB-INF/classes" dir
        // Servlet 3.0 annotation will work
        File additionWebInfClasses = new File("target/classes");
        WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
        resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes",
                additionWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
        ctx.setResources(resources);
        

        tomcat.enableNaming();
        tomcat.getConnector();


        try {
            tomcat.start();
        } catch (LifecycleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you build your app into a all-in-one executable jar? That is one way to force the download of all dependencies.  It would also let you unzip the all-in-one jar to make sure includes the jaxb-core jar.

Comment: I notice you're using very old technology.  It is so old that some of jars  had their package name changed.  For instance, for your `jstl` dependency, the groupId changed from `javax.servlet` to `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl`.  If possible, use the newest version of Tomcat and all other dependencies.  It might fix weird problems from old technology.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I package the application as war file, it works fine. But when I run the application as Main java application I am getting this issue. Infact I am able to run the application even though I get the exception. This is a simple application. But there is quite big application where I am getting similar exception and does not run the application. I am using tomcat9.0.38

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364640