# Why embedded Tomcat is trying to load com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/jaxb-api.jar?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to start an embedded Tomcat 9.0.8:

```
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(8080);
tomcat.addWebapp("", "/tmp/my-webapp");
tomcat.start();
tomcat.getServer().await();
```

I'm getting:

```
[INFO] main co.stateful.Launch: Loading webapp from /tmp/my-webapp...
[INFO] main org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService: Starting service [Tomcat]
[INFO] main org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
[INFO] main org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig: No global web.xml found
[WARN] main org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner: Failed to scan [file:/Users/yb/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/jaxb-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:212)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:374)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:309)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1927)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4989)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:371)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/yb/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/jaxb-api.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:171)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1848)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1285)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:716)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:340)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    ... 107 more
```

The dependencies in my `pom.xml` are the following:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm curious, why it is looking for `com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/jaxb-api.jar`, while the name is definitely against Maven conventions. It should be `com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/jaxb-core.jar`, but not `jaxb-api`. Moreover, my version is `2.2.11`, while it is looking for `2.3.0`. Anyway, how can I fix?

Comment: Please post all the dependencies of your pom (I mean: If your code references the `Tomcat` class, then there is at least the `tomcat-catalina` dependency).

Comment: Check the dependencies with [`maven dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) which dependency introduces the other version.

Comment: @Sascha I did, and I didn't find the version I see in the logs

Comment: Without your pom we can't really help. You have to tell us at least, what tomcat dependency you use.

Comment: @yegor256 Have you added this jar manually? Otherwise when you build using ```mvn clean install```, It will automatically download all dependent jars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat is looking for `com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/jaxb-api.jar` because `jaxb-api.jar` is referenced in the `Class-Path` manifest attribute in `jaxb-core` `2.3.0`:

[image: jaxb-core 2.3.0 MANIFEST.MF]

Sorry, I am unable to tell you the reason why jaxb-core 2.3.0 is requested in first place: perhaps it is related to any Tomcat dependency. Please, consider review [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364640/why-is-tomcat-looking-for-jaxb-jars-in-the-wrong-places), I think it may be of help.

Comment: Adding `META-INF/context.xml` file to the root folder of the web app solved the problem: `<Context><JarScanner scanClassPath="false" scanAllFiles="false" scanAllDirectories="false" scanManifest="false"/></Context>`

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @yegor256. I am very happy to hear that you were able to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to update libraries and clen & build

Comment: I also tried to turn off the computer and then turn it on. Didn't help.